# Cauchy sequences of finite sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Consider the metric space $\bf R$ with the standard Euclidean metric $d$ and let $F(\bf R)$ denote the collection of all finite subsets of $\bf R$. Endow $F(\bf R)$ with the Hausdorff metric $d_H$. See Wikipedia for the definition of [$d_H$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance).

Is $F(\bf R)$ complete w.r.t. $d_H$?

Comment: Closely related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123789/

Answer (score 3):

No. Take a dense subset $\{d_1,d_2,d_3,\ldots\} $ of $[0,1]$. For each $n$, let $F_n=\{d_1,\ldots, d_n\}$. Then $(F_n)$ converges to $[0,1]$ and is therefore a Cauchy-sequence. But the limit $[0,1]$ is obviously not a finite set.