# Continuity of Lebesgue measure w.r.t Hausdorff distance?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, hausdorff-distance

If one considers the metric space $\mathcal{K}$ of all compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ endowed with the Hausdorff distance (that is $\Delta(A,B)=\inf \{ \delta: A\subset B^{\delta},B \subset A^{\delta} \}$).
Is it true (and how can it be shown in that case) that the function $\mu: \mathcal{K} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ ($\mu$ is the 2-dimensional lebesgue measure) defined by $A \mapsto \mu{(A)}$ is continuous w.r.r the metric $\Delta$?

Comment: I'm skeptical. My preliminary investigations suggest that fractal shapes might cause this to fail. It seems that adding a $\delta$-ball to a shape seems to add area proportional to the length of the perimeter. Have you tried looking at, say, Koch's Snowflake?

Comment: It is lower semicontinuous but not continuous. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339102/interplay-of-hausdorff-metric-and-lebesgue-measure?rq=1

Comment: @Theo Bendt: As you suspected, this fails. In fact, it fails in a major way ---
 the collection of finite sets is dense in $\mathcal{K}.$ See [Finite sets are dense with respect to Hausdorff distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123789/finite-sets-are-dense-with-respect-to-hausdorff-distance). Also, the sets of Lebesgue measure zero (even the sets of [Hausdorff dimension zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73547/uncountable-sets-of-hausdorff-dimension-zero)) are "superdense" in the sense they form a co-meager subset of $\mathcal{K}.$

Comment: Thanks for your replies! Lower semicontinuous in the sense that if $A_1 \subset A_2 \subset \dots \subset A_n \subset \dots A$ then $\mu(A_n) \to \mu(A)$? How does one show this?

Comment: @MoisheCohen: I think you mean upper semicontinuous?  Suppose $A_k \to A$ in Hausdorff distance.  Choose a thickening $A^\delta$ of $A$ whose measure is only slightly larger than that of $A$ (this is possible since $A$ is compact and hence $A = \bigcap_n A^{1/n})$, so by countable additivity we have $\mu(A) = \lim \mu(A^{1/n})$).  Now almost all the $A_k$ are contained in $A^\delta$, so we conclude $\limsup \mu(A_k) \le \mu(A)$, which is upper semicontinuity.  Lower semicontinuity fails as the usual counterexamples show.

Comment: @NateEldredge Right, this is what I had in mind.